# Storing the response from ajax call in ember

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, ember.js

I am new to ember and JavaScript.I have designed a ember app and integrate the fb login in it.Now I have to send the access_token of Fb login to app backend (post request) and fetch the new the token generated by backend(django).I also need to store the new token for future call to backend.

Post request response

```
{
  "token": "b0fb466a6eac3ad87",
  "signup_done": true
}
```

controller

```
import Ember from 'ember'; 
/* global FB */

export default Ember.Controller.extend({ 
getLoginStatus: function() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status) {
        resolve(response.status);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}, 
getAccessToken: function() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log("accesstoken>>>>>>>>>"+response.authResponse.accessToken);
        resolve(response.authResponse.accessToken);
      } else {
        reject(response);
      }
    }, { scope: 'email,user_photos,user_friends' });
  });
},

 authenticate: function(accessToken) {
    console.log("accesstoken<<<<<<<<<<<             "+accessToken);
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/api/',
        data:{
          access_token: accessToken,
          provider:'facebook'
        },
        type: 'post',
        success:function(data){
          console.log('data>>>'+this.get(data));
        }
      });
  },

 testAPI:function() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    });
},



   actions: {
    fblogin: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.getLoginStatus().then(function() {
        self.getAccessToken().then(function(accessToken) {
          self.authenticate(accesstoken)
            self.testAPI();
            console.log('success')
          }, function(reason) {
            console.log('failure', reason);
          });
        });

    },
    carousel:function (result) {
          var photos=result.photoThumbs
          this.set('model.photos',photos)
          console.log(this.get("model.results"));
          },
  }

});
```

I am able to make the ajax call to backend server and getting the response.But Not sure how to save the new token for future.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct then you can use localStorage or sessionStorage to save the Token for the future use.

```
$.ajax({
  url:url,
  data:data,
  success: function(res) {
    localStorage.token = res.token;
    sessionStorage.token = res.token;
  }
});
```